NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open : Access is denied. ; Input/output error [Op:ReadFile]
I am trying to read this file using tensorflow
tf.io.read_file("Parsed_Capuchinbird_Clips")

I searched all of over google but they say to give the folder permission and stuff like that, and it's already have that, I really on this problem for 4 hours already, and I don't know what to do.
this the error I get
{{function_node __wrapped__ReadFile_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: Parsed_Capuchinbird_Clips : Access is denied. ; Input/output error [Op:ReadFile]
I am only trying to read the file using tensor file.

If your file "Parsed_Capuchinbird_Clips" is giving this error then I would suggest including the file extension as well in the code. So if this is a txt file then try
tf.io.read_file("Parsed_Capuchinbird_Clips.txt")

If this still does not work then maybe providing more information on this file would help locate the issue.

Thanks man, you opened my eyes that it's reading a file not a folder, rookie mistake.

Something is preventing the file from opening.
In my experience this is the order I try things.

Make sure that the file in question is not opened by ANYTHING else.
Permissions are not properly set for the file. Make sure you know what "user" is trying to open the file. Ensure that user has permissions to do so.
PDPU. It's silly stupid and doesn't address root cause, but sometimes if something else had the file opened and did not close correctly, the file can stay locked. Restarting the computer can fix that issue most of the time.
Delete temporary files. Look for any hidden temp files in the same folder. Often named the filename with a "~". Delete them. Just be aware you will likely lose any unsaved data this way.

